# What Blackbird variant is the one at the Kalamazoo Air Zoo?

Tags: aircraft-identification, sr-71

Which one is sitting at the [Air Zoo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Zoo) (Kalamazoo Aviation History Museum)? What variant is it?

Comment: Are you comparing [the M-21](http://www.museumofflight.org/Exhibits/blackbird) (an [A-12](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_A-12#Variants) variant) in Seattle with [the SR-71B](https://www.airzoo.org/page.php?page_id=192) in Michigan?

Answer (score 2):

The Air Zoo refers to it as an SR-71B.  Their image of it shows it in NASA livery as NASA 831. This was originally USAF serial number 61-7956 which was one of two SR-71's built as trainers. 61-7957 was the other and it was destroyed in a crash in 1968.  They were both built as SR-71B's, not A-12's or YF-12's.

Number 956 was transferred to NASA in 1990 when the AF retired the SR-71's the first time. NASA labeled it as #831.

There is only one other dual-control trainer and it is an SR-71C, serial number 61-7981 which replaced the destroyed #956.  It was made from parts of the static test model SR-71 and the aft section of YF-12A #06934.

More info at [Habu.org](http://www.habu.org/).

Comment: I'm confused by your comment that there is only one other "two-seater".  In The [Blackbird Diaries](https://www.airspacemag.com/flight-today/blackbird-diaries-180953373/) almost every single story refers to the "back seat" and a second crew member.    I believe that all the Blackbirds carried two crew members, but only the 71B and 71C could be piloted by the second crew, is that correct?

Comment: @abelenky You're correct. A limited number of two-seat, dual-control trainers were built, which is what Gerry is referring to.

Comment: @abelenky Your assumption is correct. I also found an image at the Air Zoo and confirmed the a/c number.  I've updated the answer.

Comment: @egid Thanks for the clarification.  I've edited the answer to reduce ambiguity.